# How to arrange the data in a Pivot Chart? (stacked column chart)

Tags: excel, charts, pivot-table

I generated a pivot chart from a pivot table. The chart type is stacked columns. The problem with the pivot is that it generated automatically the order of the stacks and I can't set them in the order I want
Do you know if I can rearrange the stacks order in a Pivot Chart?
I want to do this because I have some other chart type for some data (line) and the lines need to be on the same level with the stacks.
Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most straight forward way to do this is to rearrange their order in the associated pivot table. You should be able to drag the labels in the table and see the result in the chart.

There is also another way using the sort options within the legend drop down menu. But I've always found dragging items around the chart to be really difficult

Comment: Ok, but how do you drag the columns in the Pivot Table? If I click and drag, it just highlights multiple cells.

Comment: The trick is the click to highlight the column header and then grab it by the cell border to drag it around. You'll notice your cursor changes when you are on the border and can drag

Comment: Also, turning the sorting fields option to "Manual Sorting" throught the sorting options.